# Unable to get expected response for Facebook photos from an album

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook API. Trying the FQL Query from the Graph API for the first time using this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150146071791729/photos).

I am trying to get photos from the album with the album id. When I request using Facebook object with `https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071791729/photos&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` URL, I am getting the following response (before parsing to JSON object). `{"id":"https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071791729/photos","shares":2}`. And I confirmed it by printing the length of the JSON object after parsing, which is 2. When I copy and paste the same URL in the web browser, I am getting the expected response (the response in FQL Query I got). Here is my code.

```
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    String token = facebook.getAccessToken();
                    System.out.println("Token: " + token);
                    try {
                        String response = facebook.request("https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071791729/photos&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN");
                        System.out.println("response :"+response);
                        JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(response);
                        System.out.println("obj length : " + obj.length());
                        Iterator iterator = obj.keys();
                        while(iterator.hasNext()){
                            String s = (String)iterator.next();
                            System.out.println(""+s+" : "+obj.getString(s));
                        }

                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Note: I got access token from the FQL Query which is used in the URL. And I did not wrote any session (login/logout) logic as it is a test project.

Comment: NEVER post your access tokens publicly. I've queued an edit removing that, but it'll be good if you can do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks Vinay for your valuable suggestion and for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is wrong. It should be

`"https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071791729/photos?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"`

Replace the '&' after the photos with a '?'.

Two more things, you're making a Graph API query, not an FQL one.

Second, NEVER post your access tokens publicly. If I wanted to, I can now use your access token to edit your facebook information.

EDIT: When you use the Android Facebook SDK, you do not need to use the full graph path. Instead, use

`facebook.request("10150146071791729/photos")`

You do not need to add the access token as the Facebook object already has it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because not much code has been provided except for the most relevant one, let me give you a couple of ways you can access *Photos* from an *Album*

*FIRST METHOD (IF your wish to use the complete URL to make the request)*

```
String URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + YOUR_ALBUM_ID
        + "/photos&access_token="
        + Utility.mFacebook.getAccessToken() + "?limit=10";

try {

    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);

    if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        String queryPhotos = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
        Log.e("PHOTOS RESULT", queryPhotos);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

*SECOND METHOD* (Without using the complete URL as @Vinay Shenoy mentioned earlier)

```
try {
    Bundle paramUserInfo = new Bundle();
    paramUserInfo.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, Utility.mFacebook.getAccessToken());

    String resultPhotos = Utility.mFacebook.request("YOUR_ALBUM_ID/photos", paramUserInfo, "GET");
    Log.e("PHOTOS", resultPhotos);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

On a personal note, I follow the *first* method almost entirely through my application. It lets me using the *Paging* for endless `ListViews`

That being said, when I need some quick data in between somewhere, I do rely on the *second* method. Both of them work and I hope either (or both) of them helps you.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do this, but this Utility.mFacebook.* isn't working, I need to create a class with this methods?